# Sum and Count by Two different group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to print the total order and transaction amounts and counts of each account.

When I run the query below I get the following error:

> Column 'orders.order_amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How can I fix this?

```
SELECT
    trans.account_id,
    SUM(trans.amount),
    COUNT(trans.account_id),
    orders.order_amount, 
    orders.order_count
FROM
    trans
FULL JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         [order].account_id,
         SUM([order].amount) as order_amount, 
         COUNT([order].account_id) as order_count
     FROM
         [order]
     GROUP BY 
         [order].account_id) AS orders ON (trans.account_id = orders.account_id)
GROUP BY
    trans.account_id
ORDER BY 
    trans.account_id;
```

`Trans` table:

```
trans_id  account_id  type  amount  balance  account   date
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1              1       a      88      213      75      1995-03-24
7              1       b      156     66       75      1995-02-25
```

`Order` table

```
order_id  account_id  bank_to amount 
-------------------------------------
1              1       a      88       
7              1       b      156
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `orders.order_amount` and `orders.order_count` to `group by`:

```
select trans.account_id,
       SUM(trans.amount),
       COUNT(trans.account_id),
       orders.order_amount, 
       orders.order_count
from trans
        FULL JOIN (
            select  [order].account_id,
                    SUM([order].amount) as order_amount, 
                    COUNT([order].account_id) as order_count

            from [order]

            GROUP BY [order].account_id


          ) as orders

          ON (trans.account_id = orders.account_id)

group by trans.account_id, orders.order_amount, orders.order_count
order by trans.account_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be using `full join` if you thought that accounts could be in either table, but not necessarily in both.  If so, you should fix your query.

I would recommend aggregating *both* tables before `join`ing.  And then fixing the `order by` conditions:

```
select coalesce(t.account_id, o.account_id), t.trans_amount, t.trans_count,
       o.order_amount, o.order_count
from (select t.account_id, sum(t.amount) as trans_amount, count(*) as trans_count
      from trans t
      group by t.account_id
     ) t full join
     (select o.account_id,
             sum(o.amount) as order_amount, 
             count(o.account_id) as order_count
      from [order] o
      group by o.account_id
     ) o
     on t.account_id = o.account_id
order by coalesce(t.account_id, o.account_id);
```

Note that `full join` is often not needed.  However, if it is needed, you should write the query correctly for it.